# How to make foreign key in C# class for SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

How to make a foreign key in a C# class?

I have two separate classes, `Customer` and `Sales`.

```
class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(11)]
    public int phone { get; set; }

    public double Account_payable { get; set; }
}

class Sales
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int OrderID { get; set;}

   // here I want to add a foreign key to the Customer table
}
```

Comment: You mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: Which SQLite library are you using, because each library its different

Comment: SQLite.Net.Attributes @JurabekAzizkhujaev

Answer (score 4):

Please use https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

here one to many example:

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)] 
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite.net has no foreign key support but you can use Sqlite.net-extensions

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/